# Setting up smile using scala

Tags: scala, batch-file, smile

I am new to scala and trying to use [smile](http://haifengl.github.io/smile/) on windows. I am able to use the shell, but unable to run smile from .bat-script. I have written the following:

```
::#!
@echo off
call scala %0 %*
goto :eof
::!#

println("Hello, Welcome to Scala Script.....!!!!!")

import smile._
```

I have tried to put the script in all kinds of location, but continously get the following error:

> scala> import smile._
>
> :12: error: not found: value smile
>
> import smile._

I am not sure about what the directory structure should be like (i.e. where should I place the .bat-file relative to the downloaded files. Should I use the source files or the compiled version?

Answer (score 1):

If scala script need to use thirdparty library, we need do something like:

`scala -classpath third_party.jar test.scala`

So yourscript may need to be modified as follows:

```
::#!
@echo off
call scala -classpath your_smile.jar %0 %*
goto :eof
::!#

println("Hello, Welcome to Scala Script.....!!!!!")
import smile._
```